# Process unexpectedly closed with status: 0

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to launch Google.. I deleted whole my workspace (I think i did a big mistake doing so) and then tried to practice selenium again but now i am even unable to launch google in it.I am using "selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0"
The Firefox driver is opening but i m unable to launch google. Can anyone help me in it.

```
package Basic;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class SignIn {
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "F:\\Selenium\\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
}

}


Error:- 
 1524588951733  Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 2828
[GPU 2300] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[GPU 2300] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 4276] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 4276] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Process unexpectedly closed with status: 0
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:15.31Z'
System info: host: 'RAHUL', ip: '192.168.1.109', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace: stack backtrace:
0:           0x47e934 - <no info>
1:           0x47f0a3 - <no info>
```

Comment: Are you using sandbox

Comment: Chrome driver is better than firfox WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); and u need to set path in environment variables in advance system settings

Comment: Update the question with the error stack trace. As you have trimmed the error stack trace debugging is difficult. Add _GeckoDriver_ version and _remote stacktrace: stack backtrace_ retries as well.

Comment: Well as i updated my Firefox Browser it started to work fine..

Answer (score 5):

**IF** you are using sandbox then this will solve your problem :

**setting "security.sandbox.content.level" to "5" in the Firefox profile**

**Else :**
Update your browser.

Comment: Updating Firefox worked for me using Selenium 3.141 and not using sandbox. +1

Comment: @NolanBradshaw : the issue is either way, I mean with sandbox or browser. So for you its browser.

Comment: I'm on the latest version of FF and it happened to me, but pretty rarely. AFAIU, sandbox is enabled by default with level 6. @PritamMaske do you have an explanation why setting the level to 5 should solve the issue? Because it happens pretty rarely, I'm concerned that I won't really know if it solved the problem or not, while it will sacrifice security.